# Como mover con Jquery el contenido de unos div que se generan automaticamente y ordenarlo en unos div ya existentes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**contenedores ya existentes**
*aquí es donde hay que ordenar los datos generados automáticamente.
(puede haber contenedores para muchos años)*

```
<div id="year-2021" class="year-container">

    <div class="month month-1"></div>
    <div class="month month-2"></div>
    <div class="month month-3"></div>
    <div class="month month-4"></div>
    <div class="month month-5"></div>
    <div class="month month-6"></div>
    <div class="month month-7"></div>
    <div class="month month-8"></div>
    <div class="month month-9"></div>
    <div class="month month-10"></div>
    <div class="month month-11"></div>
    <div class="month month-12"></div>

</div>
<div id="year-2022" class="year-container">

    <div class="month month-1"></div>
    <div class="month month-2"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

**contenedores generados automaticamente**
*estos son los contenedores que hay que ordenar dentro de los anteriores, se generan automáticamente así que puede haber un numero indefinido de ellos.
me gustaría tener un bucle que compruebe cuanta información hay y que la ordene en sus divs correspondientes*

```
<div class="timeline-element" data-year="2021" data-month="1">

    <div class="timeline-element-heading">

        <div>contenido1 titulo</div>

    </div>
    <div class="timeline-element-content">

        <div>contenido1 texto</div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="timeline-element" data-year="2022" data-month="4">

    <div class="timeline-element-heading">

        <div>contenido2 titulo</div>

    </div>
    <div class="timeline-element-content">

        <div>contenido2 texto</div>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) para aplicar un bucle a todos los div de la clase `timeline-element`, luego es simplemente extraer el atributo `data-year` y `data-month`, construir un nuevo selector para identificar el div de destino y traspasar los contenidos.

Ten en cuenta que el método `each` devuelve los elementos del DOM y no un selector de jQuery, por este motivo, estoy usando los métodos nativos [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) y [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) cuuando interactúo con `elem` mientras que con los que selecciono con selectors usan [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Si quieres que todo sea igual, sería usar jQuery con el elemento nativo también (`$(elem).attr("data-year")`, por ejemplo).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".timeline-element").each((idx, elem) => {
    // obtener fecha
    const year = elem.getAttribute("data-year");
    const month = elem.getAttribute("data-month");
    // construir selector del destino
    const selector = "#year-" + year + " .month-" + month;
    // establecer el contenido del selector
    $(selector).html(elem.innerHTML);
    // borrar el contenido original
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year-2021" class="year-container">

  <div class="month month-1"></div>
  <div class="month month-2"></div>
  <div class="month month-3"></div>
  <div class="month month-4"></div>
  <div class="month month-5"></div>
  <div class="month month-6"></div>
  <div class="month month-7"></div>
  <div class="month month-8"></div>
  <div class="month month-9"></div>
  <div class="month month-10"></div>
  <div class="month month-11"></div>
  <div class="month month-12"></div>

</div>
<div id="year-2022" class="year-container">

  <div class="month month-1"></div>
  <div class="month month-2"></div>
  <div class="month month-3"></div>
  <div class="month month-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="timeline-element" data-year="2021" data-month="1">

  <div class="timeline-element-heading">

    <div>contenido1 titulo</div>

  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element-content">

    <div>contenido1 texto</div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="timeline-element" data-year="2022" data-month="4">

  <div class="timeline-element-heading">

    <div>contenido2 titulo</div>

  </div>
  <div class="timeline-element-content">

    <div>contenido2 texto</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha funcionado muy bien.

Comment: @ACarras Si te ha funcionado márcala como respuesta aceptada. Saludos